# background-attachment: fixed not working

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is to have the 'header' fixed as a background attachment. I've looked at different SO posts similar to this one, but those didn't provide an answer that solved my problem.

What I think the problem is, is that the image does respond to the property but the header ignores it.

Any constructive help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I'm using scss and the BEM model btw.

```css
html, body  {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("/images/gifs/dedsec_loading.gif")
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

      <!-- Banner: Begin -->
      <header class="landingPage__header">
        <h1 id="encoded-text">
          <span id="decoded">TEST</span>
          <span id="encoded"></span>
        </h1>
        <h1 class="header__ju--typography">
          TEST
        </h1>
      </header>
      <!-- Banner: End -->


      <!-- About-us: Begin -->
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <!-- About-us: End -->

      <!-- Projects: Begin-->
      <!-- Projects: End-->

      <!-- Contact: Begin -->
      <!-- Contact: End -->

    </div>
```

Comment: I find this question unclear. `background-attachment` is specifically for the background image of an element. Are you wanting to have the header `fixed` on the page as well?

Comment: I'm trying to have the header fixed on the page, so that the next div scrolls over the image. Sorry if it's unclear, my native language is not english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-attachment` is specifically about the background image of an element. It will not convert your element to a sort of background attachment, so I think the meaning of that CSS property is confusing you.

What you do have available is `position: fixed`; that will make your element so it stays in the same location in your viewport regardless of scrolling. If you want the rest of your content to overlap your header, you'll have to make the content also `position: fixed`, so something like this.

CSS:

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#scrolling-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating this](https://jsfiddle.net/2b14wtan/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, please use the short form representation of `background-image` with the below properties, read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

```css
html, body  {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

      <!-- Banner: Begin -->
      <header class="landingPage__header">
        <h1 id="encoded-text">
          <span id="decoded">TEST</span>
          <span id="encoded"></span>
        </h1>
        <h1 class="header__ju--typography">
          TEST
        </h1>
      </header>
      <!-- Banner: End -->


      <!-- About-us: Begin -->
      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <!-- About-us: End -->

      <!-- Projects: Begin-->
      <!-- Projects: End-->

      <!-- Contact: Begin -->
      <!-- Contact: End -->

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `position: fixed` style property for your header. Just be carefull, if you give a element a 100vh of height and its a fixed element. It will cover your 
whole page.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/480/tech/grayscale");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

div {
  margin-top: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <!-- Banner: Begin -->
  <header class="landingPage__header">
    <h1 id="encoded-text">
      <span id="decoded">TEST</span>
      <span id="encoded"></span>
    </h1>
    <h1 class="header__ju--typography">
      TEST
    </h1>
  </header>
  <!-- Banner: End -->


  <!-- About-us: Begin -->
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  <!-- About-us: End -->

  <!-- Projects: Begin-->
  <!-- Projects: End-->

  <!-- Contact: Begin -->
  <!-- Contact: End -->

</div>
```